# Custom Django VM Control Panel - LDAP Questions/Insight needed

Tags: django, python-2.7, ldap

I am an intern at a company for the summer. I have been assigned a project that must be done in Django. I have a rough setup going and I need some feedback of how I should further set things up. People on the techops team spend too much time rebooting VMs for developers when they break something. The solution is to allow users to do this themselves.

**Project Outline**

- User logs in with ldap credentials
- Server gets ldap groups that the individual is in ['techops', 'staff']
- Only servers that are apart of these ldap groups will be displayed
- User will then have the ability to reboot these VMs
- Server will ssh into designated VM domain via SSH key and trigger a vm reboot

I currently have the ability for users to sign into the admin panel via ldap, but not on a separate authentication page for the website. Is there a way to populate the user's LDAP groups automatically?

```
# Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}
```

I need help understanding how LDAP works(with Django), and how I can retrieve the current user that is logged in, run my get_Ldapgroups function, compare these groups to the server ldap group, then only display those servers on the /reboot page.

Please feel free to ask questions or request any additional files. I appreciate all of your time and help that you guys may provide me.

Here are my files as of right now:

servers models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, default='@business.com')
  ldap_group = models.CharField(max_length=64)

  def __unicode__(self):
        return '"' + self.name + '" <' + self.email + '>'

class Site(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

  def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):
  hostname = models.CharField(max_length=254)
  fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=254)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Team)
  site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

  def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

reboot views.py
lists the servers, when you click on a server it let's you know if it is "alive"

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from servers.models import Server
import paramiko
import socket

def index(request):
  t = loader.get_template('reboot/index.html')
  servers = Server.objects.all()
  c = Context( {
    'servers': servers,
  })
  return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def test_ssh_liveness(ssh, name):
  try:
    ssh.connect(name, timeout='1')
    return True
  except socket.timeout:
    # server is down
    return False
  except socket.gaierror:
    # invalid server name
    return False
  except paramiko.SSHException:
    # unknown host key
    return True

def server(request, name):
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  is_alive = test_ssh_liveness(ssh, name)
  return HttpResponse("You selected server "+name+" and it is "+str(is_alive))
```

reboot template

```
{% block title %}Server{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Server</h1>
<ul>
  {% for server in servers %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'server' server.hostname %}">{{ server.hostname }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django has a pluggable authentication system with a concept of different backends. django comes with two backends; one that uses the database and the other that can use an external user system.

Taking advantage of this flexibility is [django-auth-ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/), a custom backend designed to work with a LDAP directory.  Its a drop-in replacement.

You set it up and then it will automatically populate the user groups and can also do other things (see the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/groups.html) for more information).

The [example configuration](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/example.html) details most of the configuration and setup details.

As a final tip, considering offloading the restarting of the servers. Otherwise should there be a network issue or other delay, your application won't be blocked. To schedule tasks offline from django, use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a decent grasp on the django_authentication and hopefully should be able to get this going with ldap shortly. I will also look into offloading.